# How to find out where iptables rules come from?

Tags: 14.04, iptables, firewall

I used to have my own set of iptables rules on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation. This was residing in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables`.

Now, apparently after another `apt-get dist-upgrade` it looks like my rules are overridden: when I run `iptables -L` I see stuff which seems to be originating from `libvirt` or something else but not me.

I am therefore looking for a way to find out where those rules come from so that I could edit/control them. The way I am after needs to be smarter than the one I am trying now — simply searching all system config files for unique strings appearing in the `iptables -L` output.

**UPDATE:**

After running `virsh net-autostart default --disable` and rebooting all those weird iptables rules have gone. Now that I have clean iptables I know — they were previously polluted by libvirt/kvm.

Still, the question remains: is there a general way of finding out *where* iptables rules come from? Something more intelligent than guessing and turning stuff off one by one to see if it affects iptables?

Comment: Is it possible you now have [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) installed? It is a front-end to iptables and very commonly installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nope, it was libvirt/kvm. See my update to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally iptables rules are saved or loaded by scripts residing in /etc/init.d.  Assuming the scripts are using the typical iptables-save and iptables-restore commands, you could search for them with a recursive grep, for example:

```
grep -R iptables-restore /etc/init.d/
```

If the grep command output reveals any files, you can see what package was responsible for placing those files on the system.

```
dpkg-query -S file-name-result-of-grep
```

There is a chance that the file was either generated at install time or created by a regular user, if that's the case, then dpkg may not know about the file.

If the single-package-name terse output from dpkg isn't descriptive enough, you can `apt-cache show package-name` on the name of the package provided by dpkg.

Comment: But does that answer the question  *who* put them there?

Comment: What do you mean by whom?  The responsible package?  `dpkg-query -S file-name-result-of-grep`

Comment: The question is asking how to tell who or what created the rules. If that requires the dpkg command you should probably [edit] your answer to include that

Comment: I didn't see the who part, just the where part, hence the comment above.  I suppose it's really just more info on the where part, so I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's indeed a good search start point. However it is still "try and see there" method rather than "trace and find". In my case the iptables rules were controlled by `libvirt` in [this manner](https://libvirt.org/firewall.html) which does not have anything to do with the scripts in `/etc/init.d`. Perhaps the answer to be ticked would involve *tracing* iptables insert/modify calls or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the resulting iptables rules come from `/var/lib/libvirt/network/default.xml` which in turn is generated from `/etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml` when `virsh net-edit default` is used to make changes. I think, but am not sure, the rules are not stored as a rule set, but rather compiled from the .xml source and entered into the iptables rule set when libvirtd is started during boot.

Comment: That's right. The question is more general, though, rather than just about the source of `libvirt` rules. Perhaps the answer to be ticked would involve tracing `iptables` insert/modify calls or something like that.

Comment: Oh. I use the `/etc/network/interfaces` file method for loading my iptables rule set via a `pre-up` directive (I think some users use a `post-up` directive).